# Why doesnt clicking on link with react router display the content? I really appreciate any advice

Tags: reactjs

I am creating react recipe app. There is the main part of Recipe.js that displays the recipes themselves and when clicking on the name it is supposed to display details about the recipe that I am yet to set up.
But first this problem came up-after clicking the link redirects me to another page, but isnt displaying the content, in this case the lorem text.

App.js

```
import RecipeList from './RecipeList';
import './App.css';
import RecipeProvider from './RecipeContext'
import Form from './Form';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {RecipeContext} from './RecipeContext';
import {useContext} from 'react';
import Details from './Details';

function App() {

  const [recipes,setRecipes]=useContext(RecipeContext) 
  
  return (
<Router>
  <Switch>
<RecipeProvider>
<div>
<Route exact path="/">
<RecipeList/>
</Route>
<Route exact path="/pridat-recept">
<Form/>
</Route>
{recipes.map(item=>(
  
<Route exact path={`/${item.name}`} >
<Details key={item.name}/>
</Route>

)

)}
</div>
</RecipeProvider>
</Switch>
</Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Recipe.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from "./vitaminDfood-1132105308-770x553.jpg"
import './Recipe.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Details from './Details';
function Recipe(props) {
    return (
        <div className="recipe">
        <div className="first-column">
        <img src={Image} alt="cam"/>
        </div>
        <div className="second-column">
     <Link to={`/${props.name}`}><p className="name">{props.name}</p></Link> 
       <p> {props.score.toFixed(2)}</p>
       <p className="time"><i className="far fa-clock"></i>{props.duration}<span>min.</span></p> 
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Recipe
```

Details.js

```
import {RecipeContext} from './RecipeContext';
import {useContext} from 'react';
import './Details.css'
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


function Details() {

  return (
    <h1>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos ullam at dolorum! Vel odit alias nesciunt nisi reiciendis pariatur dicta doloremque at! Enim, ipsam repellendus illo quisquam sequi aliquam suscipit.</h1>
    )
}

export default Details;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how react-router works on generating the routes from an array, but probably that's your issue there. Change it to declarative route and use ```useParams``` inside your component to get the id if you need it.
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Comment: when you click on the link then what is the new url of your page ?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/Ackee%20and%20Saltfish this is one of them,basically the name

Comment: So the right way to do this would be to have one route with an optional parameter like this: `<Route path=/?:recipe component={Details}/>`. Then a prop called "recipe" will be available to Details and will contain the text or if nothing was supplied, it will be undefined (so check for that)

Comment: It is throwing a syntax error on <Route path=/?:recipe component={Details}/> and besides that there is also the Form component